# No encuentra un xpath en Safari quitando iframe - selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, selenium-webdriver

estoy peleando con un html que contiene un iframe. Estoy utilizando el `getDriver().switchTo().frame(iframeElement.get(0));` para quitar el iframe.

Aún así no encuentra el xpath. Solo ocurre con Safari, ya que con los otros navegadores funciona correctamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

código:

```
xptah del iframeElement: "//iframe[@id='classicView']"; -> es una lista

getDriver().switchTo().frame(iframeElement.get(0));
//buscar el class="MENU2"
 waitUntilElementIsVisible(titleHeaderAdvanceN19, TIME_FOR_GLOBAL_POSITION, getDriver());
```

Cuando llega al element titleHeaderAdvanceN19, me da un error de no encuentrado el xpath. Alguna ayuda o sugerencia ?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Este es el error que aparece:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Build info: version: '4.5.3', revision: '4b786a1e430'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.5.1', java.version: '11.0.18'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Command: [D1142396-2935-4D2E-98DF-71D9CE867906, findElement {using=xpath, value=//div[@class='MENU2']/div}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Os paso otra respuesta cuando intenta busca el element

```
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: Safari, browserVersion: 15.6.1, bstack:options: {disableCorsRestrictions: true}, platformName: MAC, safari:automaticInspection: false, safari:automaticProfiling: false, safari:diagnose: false, safari:platformBuildVersion: 21G83, safari:platformVersion: 12.5.1, safari:useSimulator: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, webkit:WebRTC: {DisableICECandidateFiltering: false, DisableInsecureMediaCapture: false}}
```